# How deterministic are Java semaphores guaranteed to be?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, semaphore, race-condition

The [(Oracle) javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release--) for `Semaphore.release()` includes:

> If any threads are trying to acquire a permit, then one is selected and given the permit that was just released.

Is this a hard promise?  This implies that if thread A is waiting in `acquire()` and thread B does this:

```
sem.release()
sem.acquire()
```

Then the `release()` should pass control to A and B will be blocked in `acquire()`.  If these are the only two threads that can hold the semaphore and the doc statement is formally true, then this is a completely deterministic process: Afterward, A will have the permit and B will be blocked.

But this is not true, or at least it does seem that way to me. I haven't bothered with an SSCCE here since I am really just looking for confirmation that:

**Race conditions apply:** *Even though thread A is waiting on the permit, when it is released it can be immediately re-acquired by thread B, leaving thread A still blocked.*

These are "fair" semaphores if that makes any difference, and I'm actually working in kotlin.

Comment: "_The constructor for this class optionally accepts a fairness parameter. When set false, this class makes no guarantees about the order in which threads acquire permits. In particular, barging is permitted, that is, a thread invoking acquire() can be allocated a permit ahead of a thread that has been waiting - logically the new thread places itself at the head of the queue of waiting threads. When fairness is set true, the semaphore guarantees that threads invoking any of the acquire methods are selected to obtain permits in the order in which their invocation of those methods..._"

Comment: "_...was processed (first-in-first-out; FIFO). Note that FIFO ordering necessarily applies to specific internal points of execution within these methods. So, it is possible for one thread to invoke acquire before another, but reach the ordering point after the other, and similarly upon return from the method. Also note that the untimed tryAcquire methods do not honor the fairness setting, but will take any permits that are available._" – `Semaphore` Javadoc.

Comment: SIde note - Windows native semaphores, mutexes, ... , are FIFO, serviced in requested order. The issue with "non-fairness" cases, is that releasing a semaphore, doesn't force a context switch, so the currently running thread or process continues to run and and can reaquire immediately (except for the rare case of a time slice context switch occurring just after release). For a set of semaphore based queues, where each semaphore doesn't require multiple servers, then a workaround is to use one semaphore per thread or process.

Comment: Do the previous three comments answer your question or is there anything still unclear?

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes, they answer the question -- if someone else doesn't I'll put it into an answer for posterity and such.  Thank you all, as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments on the question [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) pointed out something else from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

> When fairness is set true, the semaphore guarantees that threads invoking any of the acquire methods are selected to obtain permits in **the order in which their invocation of those methods *was processed*** (first-in-first-out; FIFO). Note that FIFO ordering necessarily applies to specific internal points of execution within these methods. **So, it is possible for one thread to invoke acquire before another, but reach the ordering point after the other,** and similarly upon return from the method.

The point here is that `acquire()` is an *interruptable* function with a beginning and an end. At some point during its exception the calling thread secures a spot in the fairness queue, but when that is in relation to another thread concurrently accessing the same function is still indeterminate.  Call this point X and consider two threads, one of which holds the semaphore.  At some point another thread calls:

```
   sem.acquire()
```

**There is no guarantee that the scheduler won't sideline the thread inside `acquire()` before point X is reached.**  If the owner thread then does this (this could be, eg., intended as some kind of synchronization checkpoint or barrier control):

```
   sem.release()
   sem.acquire()
```

It could simply release and acquire the semaphore without it being acquired by another thread even if that thread has already *entered* `acquire`.

The injection of `Thread.sleep()`  or `yield()` between the calls might often work, but it is not a guarantee.  To create such a checkpoint with that guarantee you need two locks/semaphores for an exchange:

- Owner thread holds `semA`.
- Client thread can take `semB` and then wait on `semA`.
- Owner can release `semA` then wait on `semB`, which if another thread is really waiting for `semA` by holding `semB`, will block and guarantee `semA` can now be acquired by the client.
- When the client is done, it releases `semB`, then `semA`.
- When the owner is released from waiting on `semB`, it can acquire `semA` and release `semB`.

If these are properly encapsulated this mechanism is rock solid.